# How to display data from mysql and display it one by one?

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a data in mysql and I want to display the data one by one everytime I click the button.  How to do it?

> string ConnectToServer = @"server=***.***.***.**;port=****; user id=sampleID; password=samplePW; database=sampleDB; pooling=false";

```
    public void GetNames()
    {


        MySqlConnection NameConnector = null;
        MySqlDataReader NameReader = null;

        try
        {
            NameConnector = new MySqlConnection(ConnectToServer);
            NameConnector.Open();

            string Name = "SELECT * from sampleNames";
            MySqlCommand NameCommand = new MySqlCommand(Name, NameConnector);
            NameReader = NameCommand.ExecuteReader();

            while (NameReader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(NameReader.GetInt32(0) + ": " + NameReader.GetString(1));
                NameLabel.Text += NameReader.GetString("Names") + "\n";
            }
        }
        catch (MySqlException NameException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("error : (0)", NameException.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            if (NameReader != null)
            {
                NameReader.Close();
            }

            if (NameConnector != null)
            {
                NameConnector.Close();
            }

        }

    }

private void ButtonName_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GetNames();
}
```

the output:

```
Name1
Name2
Name3
Name4
Name5
```

but I wan't is, the `Name` will appear one by one each time I click the button

like this:

```
click = output Name1
click = output Name2
click = output Name3
click = output Name4
click = output Name5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least 2 ways of doing that depending on how real-time you need the data and how many DB calls do you want to make. here they are:

1. Option #1

Initialize a class level variable for names list and an index variable.

```
List<string> names = null;
int currentNameIndex = 0;
```

on the click handler, if names is null, populate the names variable with all names in the DB. display the first item as follows.

```
private void ButtonName_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (names == null)
    {
     names = GetNames();
    }

    if (currentNameIndex < names.Count)
    {
     NameLabel.Text += names[currentNameIndex++];
    }    
}
```

the getnames need to be modified to return the list of names.

2. Option #2

Instead of retrieving the whole list in 1 DB call, you could change the SQL query to get the first record from the Table. (based on a Id or some key)

On a click, GetNames will retrieve only 1 record and display that.
On the next click it'll retrieve another record, but not the first ones.

This would typically involve a query involving a key column. Please post your table schema and I can answer with the Query.

an e.g. Query is

```
int currentNameId = -1;  // class level variable.
```

query is

```
Select TOP 1 nameId, names from SampleNames Where NameId > currentNameId Order By NameId;

currentNameId = int.Parse(NameReader[nameId].ToString());
```

the above query assumes that nameId is a unique key and that values start from 0 or greater than -1, and that they are incremental. (identity PKs etc.)

as I mentioned, if you can provide the table structure, we can answer better.

Option #1 is efficient in DB calls but may potentially have stale data.
Option #2 is more chatty but has more real-time data than Option #1.

Comment: Thank you very much, I used the option# 1 and it works

Comment: glad that it worked. for closure, please mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading all records:

```
while (NameReader.Read())
```

If you want to read just one, try put all your connection outside the method and run

```
NameReader = NameCommand.ExecuteReader();
```

only once.

Then change

```
while (NameReader.Read())
```

to

```
NameReader.Read()
```